# Change category image thumbnails to title text

Tags: wordpress, js-fancyproductdesigner

I'm working with Wordpress plugin Fancy Product Designer v3.9.5 and when I create categories and assign products to categories I get thumbnails of products. What I am trying to achieve is replace those thumbnails with titles of products.

I allready searched for code that I could change but unfortunally no success. I was also looking if there is an option in settings but no such luck..

Comment: you should probably show us the template-part that this is using. I'm guessing that you just need to replace `get_the_post_thumbnail()` to `the_title()`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet here is my website http://mobimania.si/trgovina/oblikuj-ovitek/ U can see on left the thumbnails inside design program that I want to change to title. I was also trying to track where this img code is in code but I didnt find it.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not enough info.. but why don't you search in your code for `class="fpd-item fpd-tooltip tooltipstered"` or other html selectors present in that section?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I all ready tried this but no success. I was modifying fancyproductdesigner-all-min.js that program is using but I didnt find solution

Comment: You need to find out what template is generating that. But since this is a plugin question, you should try and ask in their own forum or support tickets. This kinda is a too broad question..

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Thanks, I'll try luck on their forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution;
posting it here for anyone in future

in file FancyProductDesigner-all-min.js change

```
{"class":"fpd-item fpd-tooltip "+h,"data-title":e,"data-source":c,html:'<picture data-img="'+c+'"></picture>'}
```

to this

```
{"class":"fpd-item fpd-tooltip "+h,"data-title":e,"data-source":c,html:'<p>'+e+'</p>'}
```